# In the Unix zip program, what's the difference between the -@ and - arguments?

Tags: command-line, unix, zip

Don't both `-` and `-@` just let you replace arguments in `zip` with stuff piped in through standard input? What's the difference?

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that `-` will compress `stdin` as though `stdin` is itself the file to be compressed.  `-@` will read a list of names of files from `stdin` and add each of those files to the archive.  The examples in [the man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zip) illustrate the difference (though please don't actually use the `-@` example, it's broken and will fail on any names that contain characters in `IFS` like spaces):

> Under Unix, this option can be used to powerful effect in conjunction with the find (1) command. For example, to archive all the C source files in the current directory and its subdirectories:
>
> ```
> find . -name "*.[ch]" -print | zip source -@
> ```

and

> zip also accepts a single dash ("-") as the name of a file to be compressed, in which case it will read the file from standard input, allowing zip to take input from another program. For example:
>
> ```
> tar cf - . | zip backup -
> ```